# Capturing Desktop as Image Without Using the CGWindowListCreateImage Function

Tags: swift, macos, screenshot, desktop, macos-catalina

I've been using the `CGWindowListCreateImage` function for years to capture the desktop as an image.  In Swift, I return an image (`NSImage`) as follows.

```
    func makeCGWindowImage(size: CGSize) -> NSImage? {
        if let imageRef = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRect.infinite, .optionAll, kCGNullWindowID, .bestResolution) {
            let image = NSImage(cgImage: imageRef, size: size)
            return image
        }
        return nil
    }
```

I need to use the `CGWindowListCreateImage` function in order to capture the desktop area involving not just my application itself but also others (folder windows, the Safari web browser window...).  The thing is that I get an alert message regarding screen recording privacy if I use the window image function above.

[image]

The worst part of using the `CGWindowListCreateImage` function is that the reviewer rejects the application because the application unnecessarily shows the privacy message.  If I ask the reviewer what screen recording privacy is for, he or she says that it's for making a video, which sounds like B.S. to me.  And the reviewer suggests that I use alternatives.  I've asked, but the reviewer doesn't say what those alternatives are.  So are there alternatives to the `CGWindowListCreateImage` function for capturing the desktop area involving not just my application but also other windows.

Comment: There may not be a solution to my case.  I have taken the case to the appeal board, which seems to have ruled against the reviewer today.  And the application is back to a review now.

Comment: The verdict is in.  The reviewer was wrong.  I have not done anything wrong.  And there is nothing wrong in using the `CGWindowListCreateImage` function to make desktop screenshots as opposed to videos.  They kept the application in reviewer for more than 10 days.

Comment: And as of the beta release of Sonoma CGWindowListCreateImage has been deprecated and will in some instances pop up an alert for the user saying the developer needs to fix this. Thanks Apple.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what method or API call you use; MACOS will ask for granting access to screen recording.

However this is a one time permissions and once the user has allowed access to the app then the privacy message will not show again and again.

There is no way to avoid the privacy message from being displayed at least once.

If you can elaborate more on your question that will get you a more targeted answer.

Comment: My apologies. I was just reiterating the fact. Hoping you will get a resolution